# how to connect two transistors in series

Tags: transistors, series

I'm trying to connect two transistors together so that they share the same base and turn on together. I thought that you could simply connect them like this:

[image]

Except for the fact that i'm using only 1 input so it should look more like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fruWNX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where I have an led light bulb at the end that should be on. i tried making this type of circuit on a breadboard but the led doesn't do anything and the current isn't passing through. here is a picture,

[image]

the white and black pins are connected to the battery so what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Okay, but why do you want to connect it like this? The original is used for data, not powering a load. If you want to use two transistors like this, all that would take is moving things around, but ***what is your goal***.

Comment: could it be that led's direction is wrong? It seems like long pin of led(anode) goes to GND. It should be reverse because LED is a diode, not a bulb.

Comment: Darn Passerby,  I need to give you a vote up for improving the question presentation.  I'll get ya a vote on the answer. @Passerby

Comment: ok I am aware that using two of them to control just an led is pointless, however I just put the led there to test if the current was running. What I am trying to do is build a circuit similar to an H-bridge that I would use to control stepper motors with which has 2 sets of transistors working in series, however it wasn't working so i am reducing the problem to just this

Comment: @poifq an h-bridge uses totem polls with the load between a PNP and NPN transistor. Nothing like this. The placement is important.

Comment: The resistor values you used on your breadboard are nothing like what you show in your schematic. Did you not think that this might be important?

Comment: resistors values in the breadboard and the design not the same ,you have 2 47000 ohm resistors on your breadboard

Answer (score 4):

Two easy ways to fix this.

1. Use PNP transistors instead of NPN. NPN won't work ahead of load due to needing it's emitter lower than it's base. Replace the two 2n3904 with their PNP counterparts 2n3906, and move their base to ground.
2. Move the load around. Place the Led and it's current limiting resistor before the transistor collectors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frX3I3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, change the resistor values. 100 ohms at 9V for a led is too low. 300Ω or higher for the led resistor, and 1k for the transistors.

#### But this is pointless. Since you have both bases tied together, the only thing these transistors are doing is wasting power (both VCE and VBE). A single transistor in either setup is better. Frankly no transistor would be better too, since you are just keeping it on.

Comment: Resistors value considerations are right but first posted circuit made of two stacked NPN BJTs does work. Top one is in active region while bottom one saturates, and BTW it has to be Rbase>>Rout for the circuit works as an AND. I also believe it is quite clear @poifq is not going to light a LED (just one resistor needed) but he's going to do some experiments on that BJT AND.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me the 2N3904 E and C pinouts are mixed up. For example, the LED goes to the 100R then the 100R goes to the Collector of the RH 2N3904 where as the schematic shows the 100R should be connected to the Emitter. etc etc